# left align for list style type

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I have a simple list with `list-style-type: lower-latin;`

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/U4MV4/)**

```
<ul>
    <li>one</li>
    <li>two</li>
    <li>three</li>
    <li>four</li>
    <li>five</li>
</ul>
```

### CSS

```
ul
{
    list-style-type: lower-latin;
}
```

The problem is that by default, the list-style-type is right-aligned:

[image]

How can I make the letters left-align with css?

Comment: if you use `list-style-position: inside` the letters will come inside and possibly they become left align too.

Comment: @Mr_Green - that looks like an answer - thanks! Post it as an answer and I'll accept (It works: http://jsfiddle.net/7fqZB/2/)

Comment: Somebody did already :(. it will be duplicate if I post it now. Happy that it solved your issue :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add the property `list-style-position: inside` to your ul rule and modify the margin and padding if necessary: http://jsfiddle.net/jFxLB/

Comment: `list-style-position: inside` will flow the text of the list item under the list item numbers themselves. Also, you cannot align the texts.

Answer (score -1):

Try this code:

```
       <html>
<head>
<style>
ul
{
list-style-type:lower-alpha;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<ul dir="rtl" style="text-align:left;">
 <li>coursesweb.net</li>
 <li>www.marplo.net</li>
 <li>www.php.net</li>
</ul>
<ol dir="rtl" style="text-align:left;">
 <li>Free courses</li>
 <li>Tutorials</li>
 <li>Lessons</li>
</ol>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks.